# Userspace Thread Latency during IO operations

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, scheduling

I'm working on a project using an embedded Linux kernel and I encounter a problem of thread latency when accessing a flash memory.

My application is multithreaded and some threads have to complete a given task in less than 500 ms. The problem is that these threads are sometimes "frozen" during more than 1 second and my 500 ms execution time is exceded.

This behaviour seems to be linked to flash writes since it occurs also when I execute a "dd" command from shell to write continuously in the flash memory.

I tried various configurations :

- increased the priority of my real time threads : SCHED_RR,
  priority=55
- changed the IO scheduler : deadline => cfq (better: failure occurs after 15 min instead of 3 min).

By using the ftrace tool I could see that, during the "freeze" time, some threads and processes are still running, with a lot of "idle" task time between the others tasks (idle task timeslot duration is > 20ms):

- 2 network threads (SCHED_RR, priority=50)
- dd process

I don't understand:

- Why all the other tasks are "locked" during all this time (sometimes
  when requesting a mutex, sometimes when calcultating a simple
  16bits-CRC).
- Why so much idle time can be seen with ftrace (between sched events) during this duration.
- Why higher application thread priorities don't solve the issue.

I suspect something linked with the IO management in the kernel, as if the kernel preempted every non IO thread in order to do all the works relating to IO (network, files, ...).

Does anybody have an idea of what might cause this latency ?

My kernel settings:

- Linux kernel version 2.6.39
- Preempt option enabled
- tickless
- HZ=1000
- CFQ scheduler (Default settings)

---

Edit:

As I'm not an expert, I share with you ftrace capture (to be viewed with kernelshark):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6pJb20-D0D2NHZBUHJVRlV0aDg/view?usp=sharing

Maybe it could help you to see what is really happening on my system.

In this capture I reproduced, with an external "dd" command, a similar behavior I encountered with my application in nominal condition.

The "hole" ("freeze") is (no more custom ftrace marker from my application) at timestamps:

- begin: 469.118370
- end:   469.802940

Another little "hole"

- begin: 469.807644
- end:   469.952975

Comment: It's possible you are hitting a physical limitation of the flash storage. Meaning you could be reading/writing faster than the device is capable of, and so that's why it is making you wait. What type of flash storage are you accessing? How much data are you trying to write? Also, is this a system-wide latency you are seeing, or does it just affect the threads writing?

Comment: Priority inheritance issues? Pthreads, by default, do not do priority inheritance. You might also want to use Ingo Molnars RT patches if you're real time. Additionally setting your process *above* IRQ priority (55 is *HIGH*) is a bad idea.

Comment: Changing the priority of the CPU or the I/O requests does not help when the flash takes too long to execute a single request. What flash are you using?

Comment: Priority is set to 55 because two threads of a binary library (threads connecting and managing two cameras) are set to 50 (we cannot obtain the source code of this library to change this value). Since these thread can block application at startup, that's why I had to increase the priority of most of the threads in my application to 55... Now I don't encounter anymore the lock on startup but I saw this unexpected "lock" behavior during runtime...

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be because the kernel has decided it must flush some filesystem metadata, or do other filesystem housekeeping, and must stall your process until it has done enough.

I had similar problems and used multi-threading and a userland buffer to absorb the stalls. See [my old question and answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78157/bursty-writes-to-sd-usb-stalling-my-time-critical-apps-on-embedded-linux).

Answer (score -1):

I update the status of this topic: We think we found the root cause of the lock.

My company hired a Linux expert for 2 days.

Thanks to him we found that:

The locks were caused by the fact that all flash access are blocked when a flush of data is done by kernel.

Especially our logger module (used for timestamping...) which calls the syslog() function.

But this syslog() function blocks also the process, even if syslogd daemon is the real process accessing to flash... 
(we suspect that unix sockets used for syslog communications block until resources are available, like a bash pipe '|' when writing a lot of logs into a file located in flash).

The solution was to split all the access to flash between real time threads and the other by doing log/flash access into an isolated thread (with a non blocking custom message Queue as communication item)

And it seems that it works !

I didn't read blueshift answer before but it seems he was right ;-)

Comment: I'm glad I took the time to answer then :/